# Is it possible to use multiple one hot encoding for labels?

Tags: machine-learning

A simple machine learning, like MNIST, it uses one one-hot vector for the label. Each sample just have one one-hot vector, to classify it into one class. My question is, is it possible like this, each sample has a matrix as label, in which matrix, each row is a one-hot vector. So a `MxN` matrix label means, it will try to classify the sample in M ways, where each way has N classes. Is this possible?

Comment: You can, usually you would flatten the matrix into a single vector of MxN dimensions. Keep in mind that you probably need to change your loss function to account for a different optimization target.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut thanks for the answer, could you give me some example of the loss function which is capable for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually looking for multi-label classification. Multi-label classification can be performed with just a single one-hot vector for each label. But now the one-hot-vector has multiple ones for each sample rather than just single one.

Here are few references regarding multi-label classification for the Image Annotation task. You might find these useful:

1. Makadia, A., Pavlovic, V., Kumar, S.: A new baseline for image annotation. In: ECCV. (2008)
2. Guillaumin, M., Mensink, T., Verbeek, J., Schmid, C.: Tagprop: Discriminative metric learning in nearest neighbour models for image auto-annotation. In: ICCV. (2009)
3. Verma, Y., Jawahar, C.V.: Image annotation using metric learning in semantic neighbourhoods. In: ECCV. (2012)
4. Weinberger, K.Q., Blitzer, J., Saul, L.K.: Distance metric learning for large margin nearest neighbor classification. In: NIPS. (2006)

For TagProp and 2PKNN, code is available at:

1. TagProp: lear.inrialpes.fr/people/guillaumin/code/TagProp_0.2.tar.gz
2. 2PKNN: researchweb.iiit.ac.in/~yashaswi.verma/eccv12/2pknn.zip